# Ionic SQLite ; Could not open database

Tags: javascript, typescript, sqlite, ionic-framework

I want to link my ionic app with a database, but i got some errors.
I am running the app in an android device using the google chrome DevTools to see what's happening behind.

Take a look to the createDatabase() function and the error i got.

```js
createDatabase() {
    this.plt.ready().then(() => {
      if (this.plt.is('cordova')) {
        this.sqlite = new SQLite();
        this.sqlite.create({
          name: 'ocp_database_fuits.db',
          location: 'default'
        }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
          this.database = db;
          this.createTables();
        }).catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

> OPEN database: ocp_database_fuits.db
>
> SQLitePlugin.js:197 OPEN database: ocp_database_fuits.db
>
> FAILED, aborting any pending transactions
>       main.js:686 Error: Could not open database
>
> ```
>   at newSQLError (SQLitePlugin.js:26)
>   at SQLitePlugin.js:199
>   at Object.callbackFromNative (cordova.js:290)
>   at <anonymous>:1:9
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. In order to solve your problem, follow this steps

```
npm update
npm run build
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-sqlite-2
```

After, change this in your **database file**

```
createDatabase(): void {
this.plt.ready().then(() => {
  if (this.plt.is('cordova')) {
    this.sqlite = new SQLite();
    this.sqlite.create({
      name: 'ocp_database_fuits.db',
      location: 'default'
    }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
      this.database = db;
      this.createUserTable(this.database);
      this.createPathTable(this.database);
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
  }
});
}
```

also

```
createUserTable(db): void {
    // const d: SQLiteObject;
    db.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, username TEXT, pass TEXT)', [])
    .then(() => {
      console.log('table users created');
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log('error in createUserTable function');
      console.log(e);
    });
  }

createPathTable(db): void {
    db.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS paths (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, type TEXT, points TEXT', [])
    .then(() => {
      console.log('table paths created');
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log('error in createPathTable function');
      console.log(e);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't work. May be is due to some errors in my plugins or installations. I will retry to delete everything and start over. Because all the solutions you gave me and what i found in many forums are close to each other so it must work. I will retry and see what will happened. Thank you so much @parrycima for your help. Could you please give me your contact facebook, whatsapp or whatever so i can discuss with you. Here is my email : anfaihi10@gmail.com

Comment: Hey if something worked for you and you accepted the answer, can you please share the solution as well?

Answer (score 2):

Try to uninstall and reinstall plugin, I've tested your code and work fine

**Uninstall**

```
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-sqlite-storage
npm uninstall @ionic-native/sqlite
```

**Install**

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage
npm install @ionic-native/sqlite
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i test it but i got the same results. But i have seen some warnings in my console while installing and at the end it shows that the package is added. I think this can also give me an error isn't it??

Comment: Some warnings like this :
npm WARN @angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr@0.13.8 requires a peer of ng-packagr@^2.2.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

And in the bottom i got this :

+ @ionic-native/sqlite@5.10.0
updated 1 package and audited 61959 packages in 54.208s
found 1 high severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Comment: Ok. Which version of Ionic are you using?

Comment: Im using ionic 5.2.3

Comment: 5.2.3 is CLI version. I need ionic app script version. Run `ionic info` in terminal

Comment: The ionic version is 4.6.0 . And the ionic CLI is 5.2.3

Comment: Well, Im quite sure. There are conflicts with your **npm** packages versions. Let me have your `package.json` file. Also try to run `npn outdated` and check versions of angular packages

Comment: [package json file](https://mega.nz/#!191DkQbK!sQ9O3MKZOhSSgov3kaN1X84q0Et_FTylM-mUxRRI5hU)

Comment: Why you are using **cordova-plugin-sqlite-2** intead of **cordova-sqlite-storage** ?
Can you share your project with me? i can't replicate your same problem.

Comment: Of course, can u give me your name in github or something. Sorry for bothering you. To let you know the latest updates, i used the ionic native storage to save my data and it works.

Comment: gitlab @pcperrycima

Comment: Check your account. I've added you

Comment: Check your permissions. I cant see anything inside repo.

Comment: I've gave you the permissions

Comment: @NFAIHI did you get the fix. I am also getting this issue in Browser platform

Comment: @Shan If I still remember, its somethings related to the packages, try to remove the malicious ones by following the two answers above and it gonna work for you.

Comment: Can you share your solution I'm facing the same error with the connection I'm using Typeorm  and ionic 4